# Converting regex statement for sentence extraction to Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I found this regex statement at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation for Sentence boundary disambiguation, but am not able to use it in a Ruby split statment.  I'm not too good with regex so maybe I am missing something?  This is statment:

```
((?<=[a-z0-9)][.?!])|(?<=[a-z0-9][.?!]\"))(\s|\r\n)(?=\"?[A-Z])
```

and this is what I tried in Ruby, but no go:

```
text.split("((?<=[a-z0-9)][.?!])|(?<=[a-z0-9][.?!]\"))(\s|\r\n)(?=\"?[A-Z])")
```

Comment: Do you have an exemple to test your regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in Ruby 1.9, or in Ruby 1.8 if you compiled it with the Oniguruma regex engine (which is standard in Ruby 1.9):

```
result = text.split(/((?<=[a-z0-9)][.?!])|(?<=[a-z0-9][.?!]"))\s+(?="?[A-Z])/)
```

The difference is that your code passes a literal string to `split()`, while this code passes a literal regex.

It won't work using the classic Ruby regex engine (which is standard in Ruby 1.8) because it doesn't support lookbehind.

I also modified the regular expression.  I replaced `(\s|\r\n)` with `\s+`.  My regex also splits sentences that have multiple spaces between them (typing two spaces after a sentence is common in many cultures) and/or multiple line breaks between them (delimiting paragraphs).

When working with Unicode text, a further improvement would be to replace `a-z` with `\p{Ll}\p{Lo}`, `A-Z` with `\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}`, and `0-9` with `\p{N}` in the various character classes in your regex.  The character class with punctuation symbols can be expaned similarly.  That'll need a bit more research because there's no Unicode property for end-of-sentence punctuation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the Oniguruma lead.  I am trying to use the gem so I do not have to re-compile my ruby 1.8: http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/.  This seems to be working but I get nil if I do: reg = Oniguruma::ORegexp.new( '((?<=[a-z0-9)][.?!])|(?<=[a-z0-9][.?!]"))\s+(?="?[A-Z])' )
 and then reg.scan(text).  Should this way work?

Comment: I test you regex in ruby 1.9.2 using the string "Just use google.com's search. Do you like bing? Or maybe use Yahoo instead.".  I noticed that it produces elements with an empty space between each result.

Comment: @ArisBartee: I saw the same thing.  Could not figure out how to fix the regex.  I removed the spaces like this: `result = text.split(/((?<=[a-z0-9)][.?!])|(?<=[a-z0-9][.?!]"))\s+(?="?[A-Z])/).reject { |s| s.empty? or s.nil? }`